# tf.ExtrapolationException in simmechanics_tutorial package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In simmechanics_tutorial package while executing this command

"rosrun simmechanics_to_urdf convert.py planar_arm/TEST_ARM_ASSY.xml planar.yaml xml > planar.urdf"

I got this error message

tf.ExtrapolationException: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1329408545.377270937, but only time 1329408545.388077021 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [/Base-11CG] to frame [/XBase-11]

I think i have to create a bag file to record the transformation info. If this is right please tell me how to create a bag file script in python.

Otherwise Is there any other way to solve this problem???

I have converted CAD file from solidworks to physical XML using simmechanics link in matlab for a 5 DOF arm. In the next step of converting this xml to URDF i got this same error message. It will really helpful if someone give me the insight of this problem.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27828/tf.extrapolationexception-in-simmechanics_tutorial-package/) by [Rajeswari](https://answers.ros.org/users/1753/rajeswari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wyosae67](https://answers.ros.org/users/1693/wyosae67/) on 2012-02-22**:
I have the same problem.  I tried fixing it by adding self.listener.waitForTransform(parent, child, rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(5.0)) before (off,rpy) = self.listener.lookupTransform(parent, child, rospy.Time(0))
but then I get this tf.Exception: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past

**Comment by [Rajeswari](https://answers.ros.org/users/1753/rajeswari/) on 2012-02-23**:
Please use this stack https://wu-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/wu-ros-pkg/stacks/urdf_tools/trunk/ ... it will solve the problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first version of the package used a TransformListener/TransformBroadcaster to calculate geometry, when the appropriate behavior is to use a Transformer object. This is what leads to the TransformExtrapolation Error.

The most recent version is available here: https://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fstable%2Furdf_tools.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1